# Batch programming write dir list to text and edit the text

Tags: batch-file, edit, text-files

I would like to read dir (files with extensions) and add some text in front and back  of every file with extension.
I only know how to list files in txt

```
dir /b *.IDX > IDX.TXT
```

and you get IDX.TXT file with:

```
SOMETHING.IDX
SOMEFILE.IDX
SOMEOTHERFILE.IDX
SOMEFILEETC.IDX
...
```

and i would like to add in front and in back of *.IDX some text.
ex:

```
NEW TEXT ADDED SOMETHING.IDX MORE NEW TEXT ADDED
NEW TEXT ADDED SOMEFILE.IDX MORE NEW TEXT ADDED
NEW TEXT ADDED SOMEOTHERFILE.IDX MORE NEW TEXT ADDED
NEW TEXT ADDED SOMEFILEETC.IDX MORE NEW TEXT ADDED
```

when I `dir /b *.IDX > IDX.TXT` (list files)
do I have to put in front and in back some chars like this

```
$%!SOMETHING.IDX!%$
```

and use some for loop (WHICH I DON'T KNOW HOW :D ) to replace those chars
with my text.
How can I do that ?

OS: win xp, win 7.

ps one more thing :D
how can search and edit .IDX
EX:

```
SOMETHING.IDX
SOMEFILE.IDX
SOMEOTHERFILE.IDX
SOMEFILEETC.IDX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF 

FOR %%i IN (*.IDX) DO ECHO NEW TEXT ADDED %%i NEW TEXT ADDED
```